# Pass ProxyCommand to Terraform Provisioner 'local-exec' Successfully

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, terraform

I am setting up several servers in AWS utilizing terraform to deploy them, and ansible to configure (the configuration is quite complex). I would like to accomplish all of this from Terraform but I can't seem to get the ProxyCommand to execute correctly (I believe due to the use of mixed quotes). I need to utilize the ProxyCommand as the commands must be proxied through a bastion host. First I provision the bastion:

```
resource "aws_instance" "bastion" {
  ami                         = var.ubuntu2004
  instance_type               = "t3.small"
  associate_public_ip_address = true

  subnet_id = aws_subnet.some_subnet.id

  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.temp.id]

  key_name = "key"

  tags = {
    Name = "bastion"
  }
}
```

and then I deploy another server which I would like to configure with Ansible utilizing Terraform's provisioner 'local-exec':

```
resource "aws_instance" "server1" {
  ami           = var.ubuntu2004
  instance_type = "t3.small"

  subnet_id = aws_subnet.some_other_subnet.id

  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.other_temp.id]

  key_name = "key"

  tags = {
    Name = "server1"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "sleep 120; ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False ansible-playbook -u ubuntu --private-key ~/.ssh/id_rsa --ssh-common-args='-o ProxyCommand='ssh -W %h:%p ubuntu@${aws_instance.bastion.public_ip}'' -i ${self.private_ip} main.yml"
  }
}
```

I have confirmed I can get all of this working if I just have Terraform provision the infrastructure, and then manually run Ansible with the Proxy Command input, but it fails if I try and utilize local-exec, seemingly because I have to incorporate multiple single quotes which breaks the command. Not sure if the bastion variable is done correctly either. Probably a simple fix, but anyone know how to fix this or maybe accomplish this in an easier way? Thanks

Comment: " which breaks the command. " - what exactly is happening? Any errors?

Comment: The answer in this question should help (you need to use double-quotes and then escape them): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49176009/escape-chars-in-terraform-local-exec-provisioner